# Aws s3 copy and replicate folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy a folder which is already on s3 and save it with different name on S3 in laravel 5.4 . What I have found so far is that I can copy an Image, Not folder. I have tried to copy folder like ie:

```
 $disk->copy("admin/form/$old_form","admin/form/$new_form");
```

But it doesnot work like that. It give me an error. Do i need to apply loop and get each folder item separately? Like:

```
$images = $disk->allFiles('admin/form/$id');
```

Or is there any work around available in laravel or s3 api it self?

Please help, Its driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seriously no one?

Comment: first, s3 doesnt have the concept of folders, so copy/rename a folder wont work https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/issues/128 , funny that delete do work. for laravel it doesnt allow copying folder but you can still use http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/148/copying-a-directory-from-one-location-to-another which needs the full path for both old & new to make the copy or you would get an error. i've tried with local successfully but havent tested with s3 yet

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the middle of doing this same thing.  Based on what I've read so far, copying a directory itself using Laravel doesn't seem to be possible.  The suggestions I've seen so far suggest looking through and copying each image, however I'm not at all satisfied with the speed (since I'm doing this on lots of images several times a day).

Note that I'm only using the Filesystem directly like this so I can more easily access the methods in PHP Storm.  `$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');` would accomplish the same thing as my first two lines.  I'll update this answer if I find anything that works more quickly.

```
$filesystem = new FilesystemManager(app());
$s3 = $filesystem->disk('s3');
$images = $s3->allFiles('old-folder');

$s3->deleteDirectory('new_folder'); // If the file already exists, it will throw an exception.  In my case I'm deleting the entire folder to simplify things.
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $new_loc = str_replace('old-folder', 'new-folder', $image);
    $s3->copy($image, $new_loc);
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is how I achived it as well. But it takes lot of time. I wish there was another way to directly copy folder.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$files = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles("old/location");
foreach($files as $file){
   $copied_file = str_replace("old/location", "new/location", $file);
   if(!Storage::disk('s3')->exists($copied_file)) Storage::disk('s3')->copy($file, $copied_file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done from CLI:

Install and configure `s3cmd`:

```
sudo apt install s3cmd
s3cmd --configure
```

Then you can:

```
s3cmd sync --delete-removed path/to/folder s3://bucket-name/path/to/folder/
```

To make the files and folder public:

```
s3cmd setacl s3://bucket-name/path/to/folder/ --acl-public --recursive
```

Further reading: https://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync

Answer (score 0):

I've found a faster way to do this is by utilizing [aws command line tools](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), specifically the `aws s3 sync` command.

Once installed on your system, you can invoke from within your Laravel project using `shell_exec` - example:

```
$source = 's3://abc';
$destination = 's3://xyz';
shell_exec('aws s3 sync ' . $source . ' ' . $destination);
```

If your set your `AWS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET` in your .env file, the `aws` command will refer to these values when invoked from within Laravel.